# Naming rules for direct connections from ArcGIS to PostgreSQL?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcgis-10.1, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase

I don't have problem direct connecting arcgis to postgresql if my database name contains only letters, but when the name contains dashes or underscore e.g:"gisdb-dev", I receive an error when setting up direct connection using ArcCatalog.

> Failed to connect to the specified server. Do you want to continue?
>   Invalid SQL Syntax

I'm sure I didn't break any database name restriction on PostgreSQL or ESRI side. I've look around and can't find any solution for this problem.

Had anyone came across this problem and have a solution?

Environment:

- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- ArcGIS 10.1 sp1
- PostgreSQL 9.1.3 x64
- PostGIS 2.0 x64

Comment: I connect to servers with hyphens in the name all the time. I think you need to provide more detail.

Comment: Are those hyphens in the server name or database name? My problem is the database name using hyphens. What detail needed to add to the description?

Comment: In the database name?  No, that's not a valid SQL identifier.  ArcGIS doesn't add oodles of quotes in every statement to trap for invalid characters.

Comment: So I can't have hypens in the database name if I want to connect from ArcGIS?

Comment: Underscores should be valid, but hyphens will be interpreted as subtraction (best possible case) or a syntax error.

Comment: I've tried underscores and didn't work either.